# pytesseract failed to read number in image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, python-tesseract

[image]

pytesseract failed to these types of images ?

I am using **PIL** module to open the image but i don't know what's the problem ?
I am completely new to this topic.
Glad is anybody help

Comment: please provide more details, what you tried and how it failed?
put some example code in the question

Comment: problem is that you expect too much. `pytesseract` is not magic program which can recognize all numbers/chars. Probalby it was trained to recognize chars/numbers with some spaces/distances betweens chars/numbers - so it may have problem to recognize text without spaces/distances.

Comment: I think you are right i expecting too much from it. Any other robust way to read any type of number inside images like post above using Python language ?